# SharePoint 2013 TaxonomyFieldType in custom list has IsTermSetValid = False

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create a custom Site Column of type TaxonomyFieldType, a custom content type that uses it, and a custom list that uses the content type.

Everything appears to deploy fine. If I look at my custom site column it appears to reference the proper termset correctly. I can create a new list in the web UI that uses my custom content type just fine. However, my custom list created using the Visual Studio 2012 List template always shows my taxonomy field as disabled on the new form. Here are the other things I've witnessed about it:

- In the web UI of SharePoint, if I go to the list properties and drill into my taxonomy site column I notice it shows that it isn't mapped to a termset. Keep in mind that if I do the same thing in Site Settings for my content type it appears correct. I can do the same thing for the web UI created custom list and everything is fine (editable in the new form and the field has the termset defined).
- If I use powershell to dump out the info for the site column itself it has a valid termset.
- If I use powershell to dump out the info for the field in the VS2012 created list it shows emtpy guid for the SspId, TermSetId, and TextField. It also shows IsTermSetValid = False.
- If I use powershell to dump out the info for the field in the SharePoint web UI created list it shows the correct guid for the SspId, TermSetId, and TextField. It also shows IsTermSetValid = True.

Does anyone know why I seem to be having this behavior for the VS 2012 create custom list? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm going to answer my own question. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

My issue was that when creating a sample list for my content type (described in original question post), using the SharePoint UI, the needed Note field was getting added. Even if I had this right in my original TaxonomyFieldType declaration, I would have also ran into issues with my field values not showing up in the search refiners later on when I got to that part. Thankfully Ari Bakker has written a very detail explanation of what all you need to do in order to create your custom TaxonomyFieldType derived field, a custom content type to use it, a list definition, and a list instance. Just follow the details in the article: http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/03/the-complete-guide-to-provisioning-sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-fields/